# Suppress warnings in mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

Is there any way to suppress deprication warnings in mediawiki?
For e.g. I am getting this message at the top of some of the pages on my personal wiki site.

```
Deprecated: Use of MWNamespace::getSubject was deprecated in MediaWiki 1.34. [Called from Scribunto_LuaSiteLibrary::register in /var/www/html/w/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaCommon/SiteLibrary.php at line 58] in /var/www/html/w/includes/debug/MWDebug.php on line 375
```

You can see an example here...

http://training.shantanuoak.com:8080/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95_%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%A8

I am not sure if this is php issue or mediawiki problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the bottom of `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgShowDebug = false;
$wgDevelopmentWarnings = false;
```

If you want to keep debug messages around, just not the deprecation ones:

```
$wgDeprecationReleaseLimit = '1.0';
```

Also, upgrading MediaWiki and extensions helps with problems sometimes

Comment: Can we do something about this error found on the same page? Script error: No such module "Navbox".

Comment: This means that you imported a template from somewhere, but not all its dependencies (in this particular case, that's Module:Navbox and whatever dependencies it has).